# How to replace turn off icon action to hibernate instead of shutdown on windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate

How to replace turn off icon action to hibernate instead of shutdown on windows xp.I want my computer to hibernate when I press turn of button.I think it's possible.but I could not find answer via Google.I set the cpu power button to hibernate on power options but it didn't work.when I click turn of computer completely shuts down.I want the turn of button on start menu to hibernate.

Comment: Do you mean the button on the front of your computer, or the one in the start menu? The button on your computer is really easy.

Comment: The one on start menu

Comment: And why not a shortcut? http://www.thecomputerkid.com/2005/08/hibernate-shortcut-for-xp.html#.U-s8r_l_usQ